# How to pass any class as generic into a closure in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, generics, closures

I want to pass any kind of class as generic into a closure while making API call and return a object of that class after getting data from server, but I can't implement that in a proper way. How can I proceed?

My API class:

```
class APICall: NSObject {
    public func getDataFromServer<T>(urlString:String, fileType: FileType, completionBlock: (([T]) -> Void)!) {
        
        //API calling here and parsing data and loaded to imageContainer, now can't pass imageContainer in completionBlock
        let imageContainer = [ImageInfo]()
        completionBlock(imageContainer)
    }
}
```

I also can't call that method properly from the calling class:

```
var imageContainer = [ImageInfo]()
self.aPICall.getDataFromServer(urlString: PATH_FOR_JSON_DATA, fileType: .json, completionBlock: {(data) in                
                print(data)
                self.imageContainer = data    
            })
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53845297/2395636) might help!

Answer (score 0):

There are only generic functions and generic types. so generic not into a closure in swift

**Here is well-defined explanation** [generics as parameters to a closure in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25401584/generics-as-parameters-to-a-closure-in-swift)