# convert network manager to generic type in swift

Tags: swift, generics, codable

i have a network layer class which is currently works fine. I want to impove it for code quality and clean recursive code. All my response are like that:

```
{
    success: Int
    message: String
    id: Int
    data: [Comment]?
}
```

the only changeable part is data. it may be comment, shop, user etc.. So for every request i dont wanna write the respose like that

```
struct ShopApiResponse {
    
    let success: Int
    let id: Int
    let message: String?
    let shops: [Shop]
}

extension ShopApiResponse: Decodable {
    
    private enum ShopApiResponseCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case success = "Success"
        case id = "Id"
        case message = "Message"
        case shops = "Data"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ShopApiResponseCodingKeys.self)
        
        success = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .success)
        id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        message = (try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .message)) ?? ""
        shops = try container.decode([Shop].self, forKey: .shops)
        
    }
}
```

i want to make it generic. it should not be getCommets(..), getShop(..) etc. should be fetchData(...

here is a sample request for fetching shops

```
func getShops( completion: @escaping (_ shop: [Shop]?,_ error: String?)->()){
    shopRouter.request(.getShops) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            //completion(nil, "Please check your network connection.")
            completion(nil, error?.localizedDescription)

        }
        
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            let result = self.handleNetworkResponse(response)
            switch result {
            case .success:
                guard let responseData = data else {
                    completion(nil, NetworkResponse.noData.rawValue)
                    return
                }
                do {
                    let apiResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ShopApiResponse.self, from: responseData)
                    completion(apiResponse.shops,nil)
                    
                    
                }catch {
                    completion(nil, NetworkResponse.unableToDecode.rawValue)
                }
            case .failure(let networkFailureError):
                completion(nil, networkFailureError)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in VC call like that

```
networkManager.getShops { [weak self] (shops, error) in
//
}
```

when i try to change it a model such as  it says Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

```
struct ResponseModel<T: Codable>: Codable {
    
    // MARK: - Properties
    var success: Int
    var message: String
    let id: Int
    var data: T?

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let keyedContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        id = (try? keyedContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: CodingKeys.id)) ?? 0
        success = (try? keyedContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: CodingKeys.success)) ?? 0
        message = (try? keyedContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: CodingKeys.message)) ?? ""
        data = try? keyedContainer.decode(T.self, forKey: CodingKeys.data) 
    }
}
```

any suggest would be great. thanks

to be more clear i added to changed function

```
func sendRequest<T: Codable>(router: ShopApi, completion: @escaping(_ shop: ResponseModel<T>?, _ error: String?) ->()) {

    shopRouter.request(router) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            completion(nil, error?.localizedDescription)
        }
        
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            let result = self.handleNetworkResponse(response)
            switch result {
            case .success:
                guard let responseData = data else {
                    completion(nil, NetworkResponse.noData.rawValue)
                    return
                }
                do {
                    let apiResponse = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseModel<T>.self, from: responseData)
                    completion(apiResponse,nil)
                }catch {
                    print(error)
                    completion(nil, NetworkResponse.unableToDecode.rawValue)
                }
            case .failure(let networkFailureError):
                completion(nil, networkFailureError)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and when i call the func such that

```
networkManager.sendRequest(router: .getShops) { (response, error) in
    print(error)
}
```

it says "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred"

Comment: `when i try to change it a model such as it says Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`
where is the error shown? The struct declaration is fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [decoding a json to generic array or class in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53843708/decoding-a-json-to-generic-array-or-class-in-swift)

Comment: it says in VC at this line networkManager.sendRequest(router: .getShops) { (response, error) in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the compiler to resolve the generic type `T`, it needs to match it with something concrete. For example:

```
func doSomething<T>(_ v: T) {}

// T is inferred to be Int
doSomething(5)
```

In your case, `T` could be inferred from the parameters of the completion handler:

```
func sendRequest<T>(_ completion: @escaping ((T) -> Void) {}
```

But when you define the closure, you don't specify what the closure parameters are; in fact, you are trying to infer them. Compiler has no concrete type of `T` anywhere to infer it from.

You have two approaches here:

**1** - explicitly specify the closure's parameter types:

```
// T is inferred to be Int
sendRequest { (t: Int) -> Void in print(t) }
```

**2** - add a `T.Type` as a parameter to the function:

```
func sendRequest<T>(_ type: T.Type, _ completion: @escaping ((T) -> Void)) {}

// T is inferred to be String
sendRequest(String.self) { print($0) }
```